# Splashscreen Keeps Loading for ios app on emulator with ionic version 3.12 and 3.19

Tags: android, ios, cordova, xcode8, ionic3

I have generated the ionic project with the following command

`ionic cordova start myApp blank`

Then I installed the iOS platform

`ionic cordova platform add ios`

Then I build the iOS app

`ionic cordova build ios`

But after deploying the app on the emulator it shows the only splash screen and it keeps loading. And in the Resource tab it shows, An error **occured trying to load the resource** also it unable to print my `console.log` which I had put in the `app.component`
[image]
Ionic Info:
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.12.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.12.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.0
Cordova Platforms  : ios 4.4.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
ios-deploy        : 1.9.2 
ios-sim           : 5.0.13 
Node              : v6.11.4
npm               : 3.10.10 
OS                : macOS Sierra
Xcode             : Xcode 8.3.3 Build version 8E3004b
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to the config.xml file.

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

Ionic Info -

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-plugin-proxy : 1.5.6    
@ionic/cli-utils        : 1.19.0
ionic (Ionic CLI)       : 3.19.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.6    
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 ios 4.5.4    
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Node  : v6.11.0    
npm   : 3.10.10     
OS    : macOS Sierra   
Xcode : Xcode 8.3.3 Build version 8E3004b
```